# Trimming JSON while retaining node structure and arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

How can I trim everything from my JSON except for a few properties I specify at different levels, while keeping my node structure and array structure?

I've looked into Underscore.js and it seems like it doesn't have as much fine-grained control for preserving the node structure.  In the example below, ideally, I would like to be able to specify `'_id', 'revisions[0]._id', 'revisions[0]._clientHasViewed'` as arguments to keep those properties.

Surely there's an easy way to do this.  Here's what I'm looking for:

**ORIGINAL**

```
{
    "_id": "50cbf5214ffaee8f0400000a",
    "_user": "50b1a966c12ef0c426000007",
    "expenses": [],
    "name": "Untitled Project",
    "payments": [],
    "revisions": [
        {
            "_id": "50cbfae65c9d160506000007",
            "clientHasViewed": false,
            "comments": [],
            "dateCreated": "2012-12-15T04:21:58.605Z"
        },
        {
            "_id": "50cbfae65c9d160506000008",
            "clientHasViewed": false,
            "comments": [],
            "dateCreated": "2012-12-15T04:21:58.605Z"
        }
    ],
    "status": "Revised",
    "thumbURL": "/50cd3107845d90ab28000007/thumb.jpg"
}
```

**TRIMMED**

```
{
    "_id": "50cbf5214ffaee8f0400000a",
    "revisions": [
        {
            "_id": "50cbfae65c9d160506000007",
            "clientHasViewed": false,
        },
    ],
}
```

Comment: You could probably use knockout-projections for this: https://knockoutprojections.codeplex.com/
It currently depends on both jQuery and knockout (both are awesome libraries to use, but may not fit your requirements).

Comment: Unfortunately the dependencies are Knockout and jQuery, which is unacceptable for my project in production, since I'm using Angular.

Comment: I don't think it is tightly integrated with knockout, it simply extends the ko variable with some methods (that are largely unrelated to what ko does). If you strip out the code to deal with observables (likely easily identified) and don't mind the jquery dependency, it should be an easy fix.

Comment: are you saying you just want to provide the trimmed version as an argument for some function? if so, why don't you just create an object with the desired structure and pass that as an argument?

Comment: No, I want to return the trimmed version in an HTTP request.  I want this function to **not** require me to enter a template structure, since I will need it to quickly handle a bunch of different types of objects with different structures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ExtJs has a [copyTo](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext-method-copyTo) function (only one level), but you could create something similar with AngularJs (angular has angular.copy, but that copies the whole object):

```
var copyTo = function(dest, source, names){
    names = names.split(/[,;\s]/);

    angular.forEach(names, function(name){
        if(source.hasOwnProperty(name)){
             dest[name] = source[name];
         }
     });
     return dest;
};
```

E.g.

```
var trimmed = copyTo({}, original, '_id,');
    trimmed.revisions = [{}];
    trimmed = copyTo(trimmed.revisions[0], original.revisions[0], '_id,_clientHasViewed,');
```

Comment: This is great, but is there any way to recursively work down the tree and automatically create and populate `trimmed.revisions[]` rather than creating and populating it myself on the next line?  I'm going to be passing a lot of objects into this, each of which has a completely different structure (lots of arrays within arrays), and it won't be possible to build each of these for every sub-array.

Comment: Should be possible,  but that will make the function more complex of course.